# How to catch specific words in Python Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, user-input

I am creating a python program to deal with Clock and Time. The question arises where user puts input to set a timer for `90 seconds`, or any `'n'` seconds. Here is the code-

```
inp=input("How can I help you ? : ")
if ("timer" in inp):
    print("setting up...")
    a=int(input("Enter no. of seconds : ")
    import time
    while (a != 0):
        print(a)
        a-=1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Now I want such an interface to directly catch the specific number of seconds directly from `inp` variable.

Is it possible?

Comment: can you please provide a sample input for inp so we can better visualize what your trying to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on *"I want such an interface to directly catch the specific number of seconds directly from inp variable"*? Isn't that what you are doing right now?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the user will input `timer x` (x is the number of seconds), you can just do the following:

```
import time

inp=input("How can I help you ? : ")
if ("timer" in inp):
    time.sleep(int(inp))
```

But most of the time you will probably want to do some user input validation.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be:

```
inp = input("How can I help you ? : ")
# assuming input is "timer 90"
inp = inp.split(" ")
if inp[0] == "timer":
    a = int(inp[1])
    import time
    while (a != 0):
        print(a)
        a-=1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. But you need to specify the protocol first. Like you can input `timer` and the value in same user input using some delimiter or anything, but that needs to be decided first.

Here is an example where I input `timer` and value both using `,` as delimiter.

```
import time
inp=input("How can I help you ? : ")
# I will input --> timer,10

if ("timer" in inp):
    secs = int(inp.split(",")[1].strip())
    print("Got timer for sleep is : {0}".format(secs))
    while (secs != 0):
        print(secs)
        secs-=1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What was the error @SRP ? I tried it on my system and worked fine. Please tell the error so that I can verify.